# Windows Server 2008 - 404 Not Found Error

Tags: asp.net

I just got a new windows server 2008 dedicated server and I can't for the life of me get it to serve up web pages. It has every .NET framework installed on it has the web server role added with the ASP.NET feature checked. I made sure that ASP.NET 2 and 4 are allowed in the ISAPI extensions.

Not just aspx pages but even if I create a .html page, it still gives the 404 Not Found error. Also, I should note that it's the basic browser 404 page, it's not making it to the ASP.NET isapi handler. It gives the same 404 both remotely and locally so it's not a firewall or router issue.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated,
Justin

Comment: Justin - Recommend you post this on ServerFault.com as it is a server related question on not a programming related one.  You will get more/better results there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working, I had to remove the web server role, reboot, add it back, reboot, delete all the websites in iis manager, then create the websites again.